# Using SkPhysicBody as an "Active Area"

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm writing a top down racing game, my racetrack is an ensamble of CGPaths transformed in SKPhysicsBody with the method;

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:CGPath];
```

My car run correctly inside this shapes, and it bounce on this virtual walls. Now i need to create an active area along the racetrack. I have did another CGPath to simulate the border of this active area and i tried to set density to 0 but my car bounce anyway. I want to go over this area with my car, it is only an Active area (i have only to know that my car is over this area). It is possible to create an SKPhysicBody with a no mass Behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

physics bodies with the same `collisionBitMask` value will pass through each other. Along with this you can use the physics bodies `contactBitMask`to determine whether your sprites are overlapped. If your unfamiliar with BitMasks take a look at the documentation on it found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013032-CH1-SW3), also [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Collision_Handling_Tutorial) tutorial helped me out when I first started looking into collision detection.